# Checkmarx issue Insufficient Logging of Exceptions

Tags: logging, c#-4.0, checkmarx, secure-coding

I got the below mentioned error from checkmarx report.

"Insufficient Logging of Exceptions"

but in my code i logged most of the information

User name
Error occurred timing
Entire exception
Error method 
line number
File path
Service URL all those things
but still i am facing this issue.Kindly help me to resolve this one.
i am using Asp.net core web api.

Comment: Please provide what coding you have tried. Include your coding part, the error you are getting. It will help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Insufficient Logging of Exceptions Cx Query, it is looking for log outputs within the catch statement. So for Checkmarx to recognize the fix, try invoking a logging method when an exception is thrown using any of the following common logging framework

.NET:

```
Debug.Write
Trace.Write
```

log4net:

```
ILog.*
```

Nlog:

```
Logger.*
```

Event Log:

```
EventLog.WriteEntry
EventLog.WriteEvent
```

For example:

```
    try
    {
        Logger.Info("Info");
        // some code
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error($"Exception : {ex}");
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
```